# What folders can I delete from Mac's "Updates" folder?

Tags: macos, finder, software-update, storage

I have currently run out of space on my mac for any new updates. I've been using OmniDiskSweeper to find the culprits of my space issue, and I found that Library/Updates is taking up 19.1GB, so I'm wondering if there's any chance I can safely remove some of these subfolders. Included below are screenshots of the folder and also my OS details (I am currently running Catalina version 10.15.1)

[image: OmniDiskSweeper screenshot]

[image: OS details]

Comment: If you actually update to 10.15.5, then the space will be freed. Any reason you're not availing yourself of the bug fixes and security enhancements?

Comment: @benwiggy I can't update because I don't have space left on my disk. Which is a whole other issue.

Comment: If it were me and I was out of space the contents of updates would be deleted. Also try a utility like Onyx, it cleans up a lot of unnecessary stuff, caches and the like. That might help too.

Comment: @BrendaThompson How big is the drive? OD is showing only 80 Gb used. If you've got a full 128 GB drive, then the space issue is something else. You could just delete the entire contents, but then I'd go about running the updates, which may even fix the space problem.